# Trouble with Copying Image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have written Matlab code to perform the following steps:

1. Read the original cottage picture.
2. Obtain its sizes.
3. Show the x values for the curve fitting.
4. Make a copy of the original picture.
5. Iterate through top 70 rows where the sky is. Use functions polyfit and .
6. Iterate through each color individually.
7. The polynomial approximation needs each row as a double vector.
8. Compute a synthetic row.
9. Put the row into the new sky.
10. End the loops
11. Show the new image.
12. Show the old image.

I have tested and debugged it and it appears that the part of the code that copies the input image is not working. Here is the code:

```
function (imageName) 

inputImage = imread(imageName);
[sizeX,sizeY,~] = size(inputImage);
copyImage = ones(sizeX,sizeY,3);
for i=1:sizeX
    for j=1:sizeY
        for d=1:3
            copyImage(i,j,d)= inputImage(i,j,d);
        end
    end
end   
for r = 1:70
    for co = 1:3
        var1 = 1:sizeY;
        var2 = copyImage(r,:,co); 
        P = polyfit(var1,var2,2);
        Y = polyval(P,var1);
        copyImage(r,:,co) = Y; 
    end 
end 
imshow(copyImage);

end
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with how I am copying the input image? Thanks.

Comment: A simple `copyImage = inputImage` will make the copy, no need of loops. The mistake you have apparently made is initialising `copyImage` as a double when your image is in `uint8`. The effect can be canceled out at the `imshow` stage but there is no need to introduce it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of number format, change it to uint8 before showing:

```
imshow(uint8(copyImage));
```